# Execute one AJAX request after another AJAX request finished

Tags: ajax

One JS file is making an ajax call. Within the success of this ajax call another AJAX call is made.  The second call checks whether the email has already been registered. If it has been then the second AJAX call recieves no returned data as shown in firebug and Chrome console in the case. But the same code works just fine in localhost while the mentioned problem takes place ONLY in online server.

The hosted page is at `http://twmobilefitness.com/signup/`. The problem takes place when you click on the *'Register Now'* link at the end. You have to register twice with the same email address if you want to get the problem happen.

JS:

```
$.ajax( {
    url : base_url+"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type : 'GET',
    cache : false,
    data : 'action=check_user_name&'
           + Math.floor( ( Math.random() * 100 ) +1 )
           + '&user_name='+user_name,
    success : function( result ) {
        if ( parseInt( result ) == 0 ) {
            $( ".result" ).html( '<span class="error">User name not available </span>' );
        } else if ( parseInt( result ) == 1 ) {
            $.ajax( {
                url : base_url 
                    + "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                type : 'GET',
                cache : false,
                data : 'action=check_email_used&'
                    + Math.floor( ( Math.random() *100 ) +1 )
                    + '&email=' + email,
                success : function( result_email ) {
                    if ( parseInt( result_email ) == 0 ) {
                        $( ".result" ).html( '<span class="error">Email already used </span>' );
                    } else if ( parseInt( result_email ) == 1 ) {
                        $( ".result" ).html( '' );      
                        $( ".signup_div" ).hide();
                        $( ".signup_emergency_contact" ).show();
                    }
                }
            } );
        }
    }   
} );
```

`functions.php` has

```
add_action('wp_ajax_check_user_name','check_user_name');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_check_user_name','check_user_name');

add_action( 'wp_ajax_check_email_used','check_email_used' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_check_email_used','check_email_used' );
function check_user_name() {
    global $wpdb;

    $user_name = trim( $_GET['user_name'] );
    $MobTraining = new MobTraining();
    $table =trim( "{$wpdb->prefix}users" );
    $array_where['user_login'] = $user_name;
    $sql_fetch = $MobTraining->fetch( $table, $array_where );
    $row = $wpdb->get_results( $sql_fetch, ARRAY_A );
    if ( sizeof( $row ) != 0 ) {
        echo '0';
    } else {
        echo '1';
    }
    die();
}

function check_email_used() {
    global $wpdb;

    $email = trim( $_GET['email'] );
    $MobTraining = new MobTraining();
    $table = trim( "{$wpdb->prefix}users" );
    $array_where['user_email'] = $email;
    $sql_fetch = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE `user_email`='$email'";
    $row = $wpdb->get_results( $sql_fetch, ARRAY_A );
    if ( sizeof( $row ) != 0 ) {
        echo '0';
    } else {
        echo '1';
    }
    die();
}
```

How to make the code work in online server ?

Answer (score 14):

What you're experiencing (AJAX works locally, but not on the server) there is a delay problem. Locally everything works that fast, that you can't *see* your problem. In short, this is your problem:

> AJAX callback (A) executes > AJAX Callback (B) doesn't know that it has to wait for (A) > You can't see the problem in your local install as (A) is finished too fast.

So you need to find a way how to tell your Callback (B) that it has to wait for (A). Here's how:

### Register Scripts and move data from PHP to JS

Register and enqueue and localize your data the right way: Wrap it in a function or method and hook it to `wp_enqueue_scripts` (public/themes), `login_enqueue_scripts` (password/login/register) or `admin_enqueue_scripts`. The use `wp_localize_script()` to move data from PHP to JS and make it accessible there.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse118772jsObject' );
function wpse118772jsObject()
{
    $scriptHandle = 'custom-script-name';
    // Should be divided into separate functions or methods
    wp_register_script(
        $scriptHandle,
        plugins_url( __FILE__, 'your/path' ),
        array( 'jquery' ),
        plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'your/path' ),
        true
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( $scriptHandle );

    wp_localize_script(
        $scriptHandle,
        'pluginObject',
        array(
                'ajaxURl' => admin_url( 'admin_ajax.php' ),
                'custom'  => array(
                        // custom data in here
                ),
        ),
    );
}
```

### How to use jQuery AJAX the proper way.

There're several functions you can use: The [default `$.ajax({});` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or their shortcuts `$.post();`, `$.getJSON();`, etc.

So you can simply use something like the following - using the `success/fail` object methods.

```
( function( $, plugin ) {
    "use strict";

    $.ajax( {
        url : plugin.ajaxURl,
        data : {
            // other data
        },
        // We assume you're responding with a proper wp_send_json_success/error() in the PHP Cb.
        dataType : "json",

        // Request transformation possible in here.
        beforeSend : function( xhr ) {
            // Example:
            // xhr.overrideMimeType( 'application/json' );
        },

        // The actual handlers
        success : function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
            // Handle data transformation or DOM manipulation in here.
        },
        error : function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            // silent: Log the error
            console.info( errorThrown );
            // loud: Throw Exception
            throw errorThrown;
        }
    } );
} )( jQuery, pluginObject || {} );
```

If you want to go more in depth ***and do things really the right way***, you'll have to use method chaining. (There's still room for improvement left).

```
( function( $, plugin ) {
    "use strict";

    $.ajax( {
        url : plugin.ajaxURl,
        data : {
            // other data
        },
    } )
        .done( function( data ) {
            // Handles successful responses only
        } )
        .fail( function( reason ) {
            // Handles errors only
            console.debug( reason );
        } )
        .always( function( data, textStatus, response ) {
            // If you want to manually separate stuff
            // response becomes errorThrown/reason OR jqXHR in case of success
        } )
        .then( function( data, textStatus, response ) {
            // In case your working with a deferred.promise, use this method
            // Again, you'll have to manually separates success/error
        } );
} )( jQuery, pluginObject || {} );
```

Note: For better examples of the wrapper around the callback, take a look at [commonjs or AMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521471/relation-between-commonjs-amd-and-requirejs) and their difference.

### Waiting for other AJAX responses

The interesting - and most powerful part of the whole jQuery (and other libararies) AJAX handling - question is how to *wait* until ***A*** is finished to then start ***B*** and its processing. The answer is "deferred" loading and "promises".

I'll add a quick example. You should maybe think about building and object and separating stuff by appending it via `this.` to the object, but for an example the following should be enough:

***Example (A)*** This basically like I do it. You'll have to fill the bits your own.

```
( function( $, plugin ) {
    "use strict";

    $.when(
        $.ajax( {
            url :  pluginURl,
            data : { /* ... */ }
        } )
           .done( function( data ) {
                // 2nd call finished
           } )
           .fail( function( reason ) {
               console.info( reason );
           } )
        )
        // Again, you could leverage .done() as well. See jQuery docs.
        .then( 
            // Success
            function( response ) {
                // Has been successful
                // In case of more then one request, both have to be successful
            },
            // Fail
            function( resons ) {
                // Has thrown an error
                // in case of multiple errors, it throws the first one
            },
        );
} )( jQuery, pluginObject || {} );
```

***Example (B)*** I never tried it like this, but it *should* work as well. Easier to read, but I like `$.when()` resolved promises more.

```
( function( $, plugin ) {
    "use strict";

    $.ajax( {
        url : plugin.ajaxURl,
        data : {
            // other data
        }
    } )
        .done( function( data ) {
            // Handles successful responses only
        } )
        .fail( function( reason ) {
            console.info( reason );
        } )
        // Promise finished:
        .then( function( data ) {
            $.ajax( {
                url :  pluginURl,
                data : { /* ... */ }
            } )
                .done( function( data ) {
                    // 2nd call finished
                } )
                .fail( function( reason ) {
                    console.info( reason );
                } );
        } );
} )( jQuery, pluginObject || {} );
```

If you want to get even more in depth, read [the Docs about `deferred` and `then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/).

#### `async/ await`

***EDIT*** *As this answer receives quite some attention over the years and already is 8 years old, please take a look at the following snippet.*

Keep in mind, that `async/await` still deals with Promises. It's just synthetic sugar. Also keep in mind what `this` refers to, when using short hand functions like seen in `handlerB()`.

That will even work with jQuery.

```
( function( $, plugin ) {
    const handlerA = async function( plugin ) {
        try {
            let res = await $.ajax( {
                url : plugin.ajaxURl,
                data : { /* some data */ }
            } )
                .done( function( data ) {
                    // Handles successful responses only
                } )
                .fail( function( reason ) {
                    console.error( reason );
                } )
            return res;
        } catch ( err ) {
            console.error( err )
        }
    }
    const handlerB = async data => { /* yet another AJAX request */ }

    // Execute
    // …wait…
    let $resultA = await handlerA( plugin )
    // Now exec B
    let $resultB = await handlerB( $resultA )

    // Do something with $resultB

} )( jQuery, pluginObject || {} );
```

Comment: actually I am not using any plugin. Simple wp ajax call. Regarding server delay issue- Firebug shows ajax request complete with no received data. Let me go through your answer deeply.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Above description isn't meant to be some plugin. Just the base to write your own plugin (or, in case you don't care about separation of concerns, your own theme).

Comment: Thanks, this was a great help in a recent project. Already upvoted long time ago ;-) Also just wanted to mention that the `success`, `error`, `complete` callbacks are since deprecated for the promise callbacks mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @birgire Please [edit] the answer. I looked it up and only the first part is now deprecated. Thanks in advance and thanks for the kind words :)

Comment: This answer is so beautifully written. +1

Comment: @kaiser in the 'Waiting for other AJAX responses' examples A and B, where exactly are the second ajax calls? I'm not seeing a second ajax call in Example A.

Comment: @HappyCoding see `constant handlerB`

Answer (score 0):

For executing one AJAX request after finishing another AJAX request, you have to add the below one line,

```
 
    async: false,
```

i.e, you need to add `async: false` in the ajax method as below,

```
$.ajax( {
    url : base_url+"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    type : 'GET',
    async: false,
```